# Error shows while installing nessus on kali linux

Tags: kali-linux

I am trying to install Nessus onto a kali linux.

To install this package I then called the following:

```
dpkg -i Nessus-6.10.9-debian6_amd64.deb
```

Which outputted the following:

```
root@kali:~# dpkg -i Nessus-6.10.9-debian6_amd64.deb

(Reading database ... 323266 files and directories currently installed.)

Preparing to unpack Nessus-6.10.9-debian6_amd64.deb ...

Unpacking nessus (6.10.9) ...

dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from 'Nessus-6.10.9-debian6_amd64.deb' to decompressor pipe: unexpected end of file or stream

dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste returned error exit status 2

dpkg: error processing archive Nessus-6.10.9-debian6_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot copy extracted data for './opt/nessus/sbin/nessus-check-signature' to '/opt/nessus/sbin/nessus-check-signature.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream

Errors were encountered while processing:
 Nessus-6.10.9-debian6_amd64.deb
```

How to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you have a bad download. The file is too short. You may be able to resume the download, but I would recommend checking the checksum when it finishes. You may need to download the entire file again.